# "ls" permission denied even though I have read access to the directory

Tags: linux, terminal, file-permissions, permission-denied

Although I am the owner (pi) of the directory, still permission is denied

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/Desktop $ sudo ls -al
total 16
d-wx--x--x  3 pi pi 4096 Jan 12 11:30 .
drwxr-xr-x 21 pi pi 4096 Jan 12 11:28 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 pi pi   82 Jan 11 16:13 cmd.txt
drwxr-xr-x  6 pi pi 4096 Jan 12 11:30 openvibe-2.0.0-src
pi@raspberrypi:~/Desktop $ ls
ls: cannot open directory '.': Permission denied
```

Comment: For some reason you don't have read permissions to `.`. You must have done something to change that. Simply do e.g. `chmod u+r .`

Comment: I don't see an r permission on this line: d-wx--x--x  3 pi pi 4096 Jan 12 11:30 . As @Someprogrammerdude suggests, apply either 'chmod u+r .' or something equivalent (e.g. 'chmod 655 .') to get it back.

Comment: This Q is not about programming as defined for StackOverflow. It **may** be more appropriate on https://superuser.com OR https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/ . Use the `flag` link at the bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move it. Please don't post the same Q on 2 different sites. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic ,  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask ,  http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Answer (score 27):

As you can see in the output of your command, your directory has incorrectly set permissions.

## Permissions on directories

Files and directories both have read, write and execute permissions, but they mean different things. For directories, the permissions have the following meanings:

- `r` (read) - When present, the content of the directory may be read.
- `w` (write) - When present, the content of the directory may be changed. This means files can be created, renamed and deleted. This **requires** the `x` flag to also be set.
- `x` (execute) - When present, the directory can be set as the current working directory via `cd`.

More information can be seen [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/File_permissions_and_attributes).

## How to fix the problem

The default permissions when creating a new directory on most Linux distributions is `drwxrwxr-x`, which means the owner and group both have permission to read and modify the contents of the directory, as well as `cd`ing into it. Any other users may read the contents, but not add any new files.

To do this, you need to execute `chmod 0775 ~/Desktop`